# Why does pandas not use NumPy correlation method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Recently I have realised that NumPy correlation function is much faster then comparing to pandas.

If I perform pair-wise correlation to the ~18k features, with NumPy It is 100x time faster.

```
%timeit np.corrcoef(df.values)
5.17 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.T.corr()
8min 49s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Why they don't just use NumPy for that? I have checked both source code. NumPy use vectorization for that, pandas prefers loops which makes more slower.

Comment: numpy is designed for numeric analysis like this, and makes use of vector instructions when possible.

Comment: @BigBen yes I have checked both, pandas does loop for that, numpy use matrices.

Comment: pandas may be tracking row indices and column dtype differences.  numpy treats the data as a uniform 2d array, and can use faster  compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference does not have to do with `numpy` being necessarily faster than `pandas` or compiled code etc. Pandas uses an implementation for the correlation coefficient that is written in Cython which would NOT explain the difference in performance of this magnitude.

The main difference is that pandas uses an approach to allow a dynamic handling of `NaN` values. Meaning if a single column contains a `NaN` value, then that value will be ignored as will the corresponding value in other columns when computing the correlation coefficient.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3e913c27faeb76cf3c6f01e688a2eeee3762980f/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx#L343-L394

In the link above you can see that they iterate (in cython) through ALL values in each of the pairwise comparisons. Then within each comparison it will check if any values are nan before adding them to the descriptives.

To ensure nans can be ignored, they use an online calculation of the descriptives (mean, stdev, sse; all components of covariance & correlation) to prevent a large amount of data copying around the NaN values.

The online computation of these descriptives is going to be a fairly slow approach, but is a flexible approach when dealing with `NaN`s.

---

Whereas `NumPy` allows the proliferation of `NaN`s (which is standard behavior). So if a single value in a column has a `NaN`, then all correlations with that column will also become `NaN`. This means that the numpy approach does not need to perform any (costly) online stats when calculating the correlation coefficients.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.normal(0, 3, size=(10, 5)))
df.loc[3, 2] = np.nan

print(df.corr()) # nans ignored
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000 -0.090192  0.517099  0.358564 -0.220882
1 -0.090192  1.000000 -0.560877 -0.539464  0.260559
2  0.517099 -0.560877  1.000000  0.504788 -0.465717
3  0.358564 -0.539464  0.504788  1.000000 -0.524223
4 -0.220882  0.260559 -0.465717 -0.524223  1.000000

print(np.corrcoef(df, rowvar=False)) # nan values proliferate
array([[ 1.        , -0.09019204,         nan,  0.35856406, -0.22088229],
       [-0.09019204,  1.        ,         nan, -0.53946446,  0.26055938],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.35856406, -0.53946446,         nan,  1.        , -0.52422259],
       [-0.22088229,  0.26055938,         nan, -0.52422259,  1.        ]])
```